# Use jQuery to match current URL to herf in a UL and add class if matched

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamically created UL. I want to use jQuery to use the current URL, search through a specified UL and find any li with a matching href. If one is found then add the class "current_page".

I came up with this but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("ul.nav_cat_archiveli").find("a[href='"+window.location.pathname+"']").each(function() {
        $(this).addClass("current_page");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with [window.location](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp)  which will return the current page URL and also the [href](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp) property of the window.location

Comment: Excellent! Got to be the quickest answer ever! I changed the .pathname to .href and it works exactly as required. Thank you.

Comment: document.location.pathname worked for me. window.location.href did not.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var windowLocationPathname = "/HTMLPage16.htm";  // For testing purpose.

            //Or

            //var windowLocationPathname = window.location.pathname;

            $('ul.nav_cat_archiveli').find('a[href^="' + windowLocationPathname + '"]').addClass('currentPage');
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .nav_cat_archiveli
        {
            list-style: none;
        }

        a.currentPage
        {
            color: Red;
            background-color: Yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="nav_cat_archiveli">
        <li><a href="/HTMLPage14.htm">Test 1 (/HTMLPage14.htm)</a></li>
        <li><a href="/HTMLPage15.htm">Test 2 (/HTMLPage15.htm)</a></li>
        <li><a href="/HTMLPage16.htm">Test 3 (/HTMLPage16.htm)</a></li>
        <li><a href="/HTMLPage17.htm">Test 4 (/HTMLPage17.htm)</a></li>        
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ( var windowLocationPathname = "/HTMLPage16.htm"; )  this for testing purpose only.delete that line use ( var windowLocationPathname = window.location.pathname; )