# Auto expand JQuery nested menu depending on url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this to get a expandable menu in my site

```
        $(document).ready(function () {                
            $('li.category').addClass('plusimageapply');
            $('li.category').children().addClass('selectedimage');
            $('li.category').children(":not(a)").hide();
            $('li.category').each(
            function (column) {
                $(this).click(function (event) {
                    if (this == event.target) {
                        if ($(this).is('.plusimageapply')) {
                            $(this).children().show(200);
                            $(this).removeClass('plusimageapply');
                            $(this).addClass('minusimageapply');
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).children(":not(a)").hide(200);
                            $(this).removeClass('minusimageapply');
                            $(this).addClass('plusimageapply');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            );
        });
```

How do i make it auto expand to the current menu? My links is in the format

```
/Article/Category1/Category3
```

If i am at this URL I want Category3 expanded which is under Category1. A menu item is in format

```
<li class="category">
    <a href"/Article/Category1/Category3/">Category3</a>
    <ul> ... [more sub-categories] ... </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.location.pathname` to match it to your menu's links.

See this question to get an idea on how to do that with jQuery:

[Use jQuery to match current URL to herf in a UL and add class if matched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223005/use-jquery-to-match-current-url-to-herf-in-a-ul-and-add-class-if-matched)

Comment: How would o do this? (I have never used either javascript nor jquery before)

Comment: Used this:                 $("#categories").find("a[href='" + window.location.pathname + "']").each(function () {
                    $(this).parentsUntil(".categories").show();
                });